# Multiple child nodes of the same name in xml to convert to xsl

Tags: json, xml, xslt

**Input XML**

```
<Address country="USA" countryISO2Code="US">
    <Street addr="GH Nagar"/>
    <Street addr="Naboor"/>
    <Street addr="Besides Al Drive Inn"/>
</Address>
```

**Expected Output response**

```
"address": {
    "country": "USA",
    "countryISO2Code": "US",
    "Street1": "GH Nagar" ,
    "Street2": "Naboor" ,
    "Street3": "Besides Al Drive Inn" 
}
```

can anyone suggest to write the xsl for the above please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"></xsl:output>
<xsl:template match="Address">
    <xsl:text>"address":{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xa;&quot;', local-name(.), '&quot;: &quot;', ., '&quot;,')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="Street">
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',local-name(.), position(), '&quot;: &quot;',@addr,'&quot;,')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```
"address":{
"country": "USA",
"countryISO2Code": "US",
"Street1": "GH Nagar",
"Street2": "Naboor",
"Street3": "Besides Al Drive Inn",
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It gives me some idea to proceed. But now my response is as below                                                                            
 "#text": "\"Street1\"=\"address1\";\"Street2\"=\"address2\";\"Street3\"=\"address3\";" . I want the response as "Street1" : "address1", "Street2" :"address2", "Street3 : "address3"  . Can you help to get it

Comment: the suggested does not work quite well. can you please have another look at it. I have made some modifications to my question.

Comment: my xsl is 

 <xsl:for-each select="./Address/Street">
  <xsl:text></xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',local-name(.), position(), '&quot;: &quot;',@addr,'&quot;,')" />
 </xsl:for-each>

the out put is 

"#text": "\"Street1\": \"address1\",\"Street2\": \"address2\",\"Street3\": \"address3\",",

expected output is 

  "Street1": "GH Nagar" ,
   "Street2": "Naboor" ,
   "Street3": "Besides Al Drive Inn" 
  . See answer section once please.

Comment: it is not working .see my second answer above for reference. any other solutions? Please

Answer (score -1):

It is not working as you suggested. can you please check the below. I am able to get the other values except the "Street" one's.

Request you to suggest the changes only for Street sections only.

my xsl is

```
<xsl:for-each select="./Address/Street">
    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',local-name(.), position(), '&quot;: &quot;',@addr,'&quot;,')" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

the out put is

```
   #text": "\"Street1\": \"address1\",\"Street2\": \"address2\",\"Street3\": \"address3\",",
```

expected output is

"Street1": "GH Nagar" ,
      "Street2": "Naboor" ,
      "Street3": "Besides Al Drive Inn"